# Avoid that all workers get re-spawned at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, uwsgi

I am running uwsgi with the parameter `max-requests=15000` so that each worker gets recycled after processing 15K requests. Also in order to avoid that more than one worker gets recycled at once if they reach the maximum number of requests at the same time, I used `max-requests-delta=1000`. But it seems that once the workers reach the maximum number of processed requests, they still get re-cycled at the same time.

I am using `uwsgi 2.0.15` with the following params.

```
master = true
multiprocess = true
touch-chain-reload = true
lazy-apps = true 
harakiri = 30
harakiri-verbose = true
max-requests = 15000
max-requests-delta = 1000
processes = 8
enable-threads = true
thunder-lock = true
offload-threads = 1
threads = 4
```

Is there please a way to avoid that behaviour because the reload of all the workers at once causes a latency spike.

Comment: Did you try with a bigger `max-requests-delta`?

Comment: Yes. Actually, when the workers reach the maximum number of requests they all reloaded at max-request and no worker keeps processing the requests until max-requests-delta.

Answer (score 0):

`max-requests-delta` works only with `uwsgi >= 2.1`

Comment: Not seeing a 2.1 version released at this point in time.  But it looks like this was added a few years ago?